# Table Calc - with IF statement? - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

We have YTD data only. I've been trying to get a MTD running across the table.
So I thought I can run a Table calculation type - "Difference From" previous month.

This works well except for the first month of the year.
Jan MTD = Jan YTD   NOT   Jan YTD less Dec YTD
So January numbers are never right.

Is there a way to say, If month = "Jan" don't perform the table calc?

regards
Gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something like

```
ZN(SUM([YTD])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([YTD])),-1)
```

Then, for the first entry, LOOKUP() will return null. All you need to do is to return 0 instead, using ZN()

```
ZN(SUM([YTD])) - ZN(LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([YTD])),-1))
```

In case you don't know, you need to go to Edit Table Calculation..., then Edit Formula...

EDIT: I understand you have a bigger problem, that is your rolling sum restarts every year. In that case you really need an IF statement, but it is possible to overcome your "it's not always the same starting month" problem. You just need to check if that month is the first in your list or multiple of 12:

```
IIF(-FIRST()%12 = 0,
ZN(SUM([YTD])),
ZN(SUM([YTD])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([YTD])), -1))
```

You just have to understand the FIRST() function. It will return the distance from the current position to the starting position. So, if you start in February, in August First() will return -6.
And the modulo operator will guarantee you restart every 12 months

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Inox.
You are correct.

However I was intending more like this:

```
IIF(min(month([period_date]))=1,
ZN(SUM([YTD])),
ZN(SUM([YTD])) - LOOKUP(ZN(SUM([YTD])), -1))
```

Since the formula is an aggregate, I had to use "min" for the date. That was my problem using the IIF function, which was not apparent in my question.

This will produce MTD beyond 1 year, When it reaches the second January, it will not subtract Dec YTD.

Only problem I have now though is, if you begin the table on a month other than January... ie Feb.
Feb MTD is not Feb YTD??
(this is another problem, my report is to produce a rolling 12 month)... ie Feb to Jan, Mar to Feb)

So far, I'm just displaying 2 years to get over this, so forcing it to start on January. Not really a solution, but it gets the information across 12 months.

Comment: I think I understand now, let me get some advice on my answer